# how to show xy coordinatel in cv2.imshow (python)

Tags: python, opencv

How to show xy coordinate like picture 1. Sometime it shows and sometime doesnt show. I dont understand. Has everyone can tell me? Thankyou
[picutures1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrjw1.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use matplotlib.pyplot module and use following commands in your code if you just want to see coordinates

```
path = r'C:\Users\Pictures\result.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thankyou very much. But i use jupyter notebook, i took your code and result shows x axis and y axis like a picture.

Comment: sorry i cant show you picture to you i'm beginner this site.

Comment: @TryTHANI use plt.axis("off") before plt.imshow. This will turn it off.